# App pushed to heroku successful but how to reference filenames correctly so it work online as it did in localhost

Tags: python, flask, heroku, os.path

So, I have successfully pushed my App to Heroku and it opens!
[faces-application](https://faces-application.herokuapp.com) but now the uploads and functionality are broken.

I'm almost certain the way I am referencing filenames is the issue now its not on my localhost machine.

[image: project structure]

[image: heroku file structure (might just be slug - I'm not sure)]

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER_FACES = 'static/uploads/faces/'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_FACES'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER_FACES
```

```
@app.route("/AddFace", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_face():
    if 'image' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['image']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

# I think the issue is here, how I am saving the file and handling it.
# If someone could please share some insight into the correct way to 
# handle files in heroku hosted python flask apps.

        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_FACES'], filename))
        
        copyfile("static/uploads/faces/" + filename, "faces/" + filename)
        flash('Face successfully uploaded, saved and displayed')
        return render_template('addface.html', filename=filename)
    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are -> png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template("addface.html")
```

```
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951941+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-24 16:54:47,949] ERROR in app: Exception on /NameTag [GET]
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951955+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951956+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951957+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951957+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951958+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951958+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951959+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951959+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951960+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951961+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951961+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951961+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951962+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/gui.py", line 194, in name
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951963+00:00 app[web.1]: images = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder, "nametag"))
2020-08-24T16:54:47.951969+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static/nametag'
```

Do I need to structure my application so that everything resides within /app/ ?
[image: /app/]

I have changed the project structure and created a new build.  Pushed to Heroku and the app opened as previously.

[heroku deployment live](https://faces-application.herokuapp.com)

However, I am still receiving a no file found error.

[image: new structure]

I modified the references to include app/

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER_FACES = '/app/static/uploads/faces/'
```

But this error persists:

```
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942622+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-25 08:30:26,940] ERROR in app: Exception on /AddFace [POST]
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942634+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942635+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942635+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942636+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942636+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942637+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942637+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942637+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942638+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942638+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942638+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942638+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942639+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942639+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/gui.py", line 139, in add_face
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942640+00:00 app[web.1]: file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_FACES'], filename))
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942640+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3066, in save
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942640+00:00 app[web.1]: dst = open(dst, "wb")
2020-08-25T08:30:26.942646+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static/uploads/faces/Bret_Point.jpg'
2020-08-25T08:30:26.943461+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.32.185.71 - - [25/Aug/2020:08:30:26 +0000] "POST /AddFace HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://faces-application.herokuapp.com/AddFace" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
```

The images in static/sample/ load successfully on the appropriate pages.

[image: static images working]

But when attempting to upload an image to use, the file cannot be found.

I have been reading that Heroku uses /tmp/ for uploads....

[heroku tmp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43132396/12809111)

Do I need to upload to the tmp/ directory?

Comment: 1. Can it be that the folder /uploads/faces/ has never been created on Heroku? 2. Please post stacktrace

Comment: I think the issue is my project structure I am going to restructure within /app/ directory and re-push to heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

To use the temporary/ephemiral storage on heroku you must reference /tmp as your upload destination.

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER_FACES = '/tmp/'
```

Modifying the reference (shown above) from app/static/... to /tmp/ worked! However, the copy instruction after did not.

```
copyfile("/tmp/" + filename, "tmp/faces/" + filename)
```

I imagine that if one can add a file to the tmp directory they should be able to add a directory to tmp as well.  Its possible I need to create the faces directory in tmp first, before I attempt the copyfile and that is why I am receiving an error regarding that line.

Nevertheless, to access temporary storage on Heroku deployed apps use

```
/tmp/
```