# Change global variables programmatically using Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, constants

I currently have an application built with Express.js that runs via Heroku. I need to define a global variable that I can decrement each time a specific function is called, but I'm not sure how to do that programatically. I have a file of constants called `consts.js` and was trying to just set the variable (REMAINING) as follows: `CONST.REMAINING -= 1` whenever the function is called, but unfortunately that doesn't work. What is a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good explanation of Heroku’s ephemeral filesystem which is a good place [to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416738/how-to-use-herokus-ephemeral-filesystem). In a nutshell, do not use the `/tmp` to store any variables or application level data as it will get destroyed.

It is suggested to use Amazon S3 or a similar durable store. It may be overkill for a single variable but I would look at using [Redis](https://redis.io/) just because of its speed. You could also look at programmatic access of [Heroku config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#programmatic-access) as well.