# Multer trying to create a new folder when one already exists

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, multer

I'm using Multer to manage image uploads, and when running my app on my local machine everything works perfectly. But now that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku I get this error in my application logs:

> Unhandled rejection Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir
>   '/public'

...which seems like it's trying to create a directory rather than using the existing one (like it does on my local machine)

This is my the code I'm using for Multer:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, 'public/img/')   },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname)
} })

var upload = multer({storage: storage})


router.post('/:propertyid', upload.single('img'), function(req, res) {
  Property.update({
      img: req.file.filename
    }, {
    where: {
      id: req.params.propertyid,
   }
  }).then(updatedProperty => {
        res.redirect('/admin/' + updatedProperty)
  })
});
```

The public/img directory already exists and when testing it, it runs fine with correct filenames and end up in the correct place. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dynos have an ephemeral filesystem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12418985/3137842) answer by Naaman Newbold, explains very well what that means.

TL;DR:
Dynos' filesystem shouldn't be used to store any permanent storage or data besides what is deployed. In order to do use a storage, [AWS S3 can be used](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `fs-extra` to create folder it will sync and create folder like below in below code I am creating directory by `user_id` and uploading multiple images so i have used `fs.mkdirsSync(path)` in my code

```
let fs = require('fs-extra');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    let Id = req.body.id;
    let path = `tmp/daily_gasoline_report/${Id}`;
    fs.mkdirsSync(path);
    cb(null, path);
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // console.log(file);

    let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
    let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + extension);
}
})
```