# Asynchronous processing when using Celery in a Django application (Heroku)

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, celery

I am developing an application that uses the Whisper API to convert uploaded audio files into text.
I am trying to use Celery for asynchronous processing, but I can't seem to reference the media file properly.
I get a "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/media/audio/xxx.mp3'" error.
Before the asynchronous processing, I was able to reference the file with no problem.

What should we do in such a case?

・setting.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

・views.py

```
upload_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "audio")
 audio_file_path = os.path.join(upload_path, file)
 convert_text.delay(audio_file_path)
```

・tasks.py

```
@shared_task
 def convert_text(audio_file_path):
  openai.api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  audio_file= open(audio_file_path, "rb")
  transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file)
  text_data = transcript["text"]
```

Comment: The correct way to run this on heroku is have the celery worker run on its own dyno, in which case it would have a separate filesystem from that of the Django dyno.  Guessing this is why you see 'file not found' when running the background task.  You may wish to read about Heroku's ephemeral filesystems and why S3 is preferable storage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12418985/2052575